# Adding a UIView subclass with xib to UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, iphone-sdk-4.1

What am I doing wrong here?

Created:

CustomTab.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTab : UIView {
 IBOutlet UIView *view;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view;

@end
```

CustomTab.m

```
#import "CustomTab.h"
@implementation CustomTab    
@synthesize view;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

- XIB file set its files owner to be CustomTab's class, hooked up the view

In my UIViewController class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];   

   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40); // Replacing with your dimensions 
   CustomTab *myObj = [[CustomTab alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

   [self.view addSubview:myObj.view];
   [myObj release];
}
```

The subview doesnt appear on the screen. What am I missing?

Comment: What are you expecting to appear in IB?

Comment: how are you detecting that view didnt appear, give different colors to the view and check

Comment: What do you mean? Im expecting to see my custom UIView on top of my UIViewController subclass when the app loads

Comment: @Warrior the UIViewController subclass is one colour, my UIView's subclass is a different colour within the XIB, I see only 1 colour when the app starts (the UIViewControllers)

Comment: have you tried programmatically instead of IB

Comment: No, but I'd like to use IB if I can...

Comment: Can you attach the .xib file? Might help a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nib file does not bind itself to your UIView automatically. If your view is owner, I guess you can use `loadNibNamed:owner:` of `NSBundle` interface to load your view after your have init your view.